# Covariant Exterior Derivative action on the $\mathrm{End}(E)$-valued p-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles, exterior-algebra

Suppose I define an operator $d_A$ by its action on sections $s\in \Gamma(E)=\Omega_M^0(E)$ of some vector bundle $\Pi:E\rightarrow M$ in a trivializing neighbourhood $U\subset M$ as
$$ d_As|_U=(ds+A\wedge s)|_U$$
for some connection $A=(A^i_j)$ with $A^i_j\in \Omega^1(U)$. By writing $\omega\in\Omega^r_M(E)$ as $\omega=e_i\wedge \omega^i$ where $\omega^i\in \Omega^r(M)$ and $e_i\in \Gamma(E)$ are local basis sections, and imposing, 
$$d_A(\eta\wedge \omega^i)=d_A\eta\wedge \omega^i+(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(\eta)}\eta\wedge d\omega^i\qquad \forall \eta\in \Omega^r_M(E)\quad (1)$$
I've shown, 
$$d_A\omega=d_A(e_i\wedge \omega^i)=d_Ae_i\wedge \omega^i+(-1)^0e_i\wedge d\omega^i\\
=de_i\wedge\omega^i+A\wedge e_i\wedge \omega^i+e_i\wedge d\omega^i\\
=d(\omega)-e_i\wedge d\omega^i+A\wedge\omega+e_i\wedge d\omega^i\\
=d\omega+A\wedge \omega
$$
 Now suppose I have $\sigma\in \Gamma(\mathrm{End}(E))=\Omega^0_M(\mathrm{End}(E))$, I have been told that one can extend $d_A$ as a map, 
$$d_A:\Omega^r_M(\mathrm{End}(E))\rightarrow \Omega_M^{r+1}(\mathrm{End}(E)) $$
by first imposing, 
$$d_A(\sigma)s=d_A(\sigma s)-\sigma d_As\quad (2)$$
to show, 
$$d_A(\mu\wedge \alpha)=d_A\mu\wedge \alpha+(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(\mu)}(\mu\wedge d_A\alpha)\qquad\forall \mu\in \Omega_M^p(\mathrm{End}(E)),\alpha\in\Omega_M^q(E)$$
then it follows that, 
$$d_A(\mu\wedge \beta)=d_A\mu\wedge \beta+(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(\mu)}(\mu\wedge d_A\beta)\qquad\forall \mu\in \Omega_M^p(\mathrm{End}(E)),\beta\in\Omega_M^q(\mathrm{End}(E))$$
It also apparently follows that if $\mu\in \Omega_M^2(\mathrm{End}(E))$ then, 
$$d_A\mu=d\mu+A\wedge \mu-\mu\wedge A$$
Here is my confused attempt, maybe consider them more as ideas:

From (2), if I ASSUME that I can do the following,

$d_A(\sigma\wedge s)=d(\sigma\wedge s)+A\wedge\sigma\wedge s
=(d\sigma)\wedge s+\sigma\wedge ds+A\wedge\sigma\wedge s
$

Combining with (2) we have,

$(d_A\sigma)\wedge s=(d\sigma)\wedge s+\sigma\wedge ds+A\wedge\sigma\wedge s-\sigma\wedge ds-\sigma\wedge A\wedge s\\
=d\sigma\wedge s+A\wedge\sigma\wedge s-\sigma\wedge A\wedge s\\
=(d\sigma+A\wedge\sigma-\sigma\wedge A)\wedge s\\
\implies d_A\sigma=d\sigma+A\wedge\sigma-\sigma\wedge A
$

Then, if we write $\omega\in \Omega_M^p(\mathrm{End}(E))$ as $\omega=f_i\wedge \omega^i$ where $f^i\in \Gamma(\mathrm{End}(E))=\Omega_M^0(\mathrm{End}(E))$, and if I also ASSUME that (1) holds with for $\eta\in \Omega_M^r(\mathrm{End}(E))
$ then,

$d_A\omega=d_A(f_i\wedge \omega^i)=d_Af_i\wedge \omega^i+(-1)^0f_i\wedge d\omega^i\\
=df_i\wedge \omega^i+A\wedge f^i\wedge\omega^i-f^i\wedge A\wedge \omega^i+f_i\wedge d\omega^i \\
=d(\omega)-f^i\wedge d\omega^i+A\wedge\omega-(-1)^{(r)}f^i\wedge\omega^i\wedge A+f_i\wedge d\omega^i\\
=d\omega+A\wedge\omega-(-1)^r\omega\wedge A
$

which gives the $\Omega^2_M(\mathrm{End}(E))$ as a corollary.

I've had some other thoughts, none of them well enough formulated to write down, any help with the above would be very much appreciated. There is a reference:
https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/vb.pdf page 35.